# What was left out in the anime adaptation of Sugawara announcing that Sherry is his future wife?

Tags: gate

I was watching episode 20 and my friend said that they cut a lot of stuff out in the scene with Sugawara and Sherry. Could someone provide the details of what was left out from this scene in the anime adaptation? In other words, what drove Sugawara to finally give in to Sherry, where in the previous episode he was giving her the cold shoulder?